# Sending Randomly generated Value from child process to parent process

Tags: c, pipe

I have written a code that generates a random number in the child process using rand()... I need to send this random value to the parent process using pipe(). when I use read() and write () the values received by the parent is 0 instead of the random number.

I am getting no error just the output is Value received is : 0.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<fcntl.h>


int main ()
{

    pid_t Cpid;
    int fd[2];  

    int rVal;



    //pid will store the value of fork()
    Cpid = fork();
    pipe(fd);       

    if( Cpid == 0) 
    {

        //CHILD
        rVal = rand()%100;
    ;
//this is in child process
    close (fd[0]);
    rVal = rand()%100;
    write(fd[1], &rVal,sizeof (rVal));
    close (fd[1]);

        printf(" Child Pid : %d sending random value : %d to parent : %d\n", 
    getpid(), rVal, getppid());


    }


    else if(Cpid != 0 )
    {

        printf (" Parent PID : %d\n", getpid());
        //this is the parent process
        close(fd[1]);
        read(fd[0], &rVal, sizeof(rVal));
        printf(" value recieved is : %d\n", rVal);
        close(fd[0]);
        printf(" value recieved by parent : %d\n", rVal);

    }



    return 0;


}
```

Comment: How would you know if you were getting an error? The code doesn’t check for errors. See the return value of `read` (and `write`). Also, please try to provide enough code for a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should setup the pipe before forking the children. Otherwise, the parent and the children will use different pipes, and will not be able to talk to each other.

```
int main ()
{

    pid_t Cpid;
    int fd[2];  

    // Create the pipe BEFORE forking.
    pipe(fd);       

    //pid will store the value of fork()
    Cpid = fork();

    if( Cpid == 0) 
        .. REST OF CODE ~~~
```